# How to send char* type parameters in Python using ctypes?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a problem using ctypes, Python library.

I tried to run my C code in python, but it didn't works.

```
//this is p.c File
#include <stdio.h>
void printing(char* string){
    printf("%s",string);
}
```

As you can see, it's a very simple code that receives string with parameters and print.

So I tried made that file as DLL, and compiled with gcc 64bit version. like this

```
gcc --shared -op.dll p.o
gcc -fPIC -c p.c
```

And then, I ran this code in Python

```
#This is my Python code
from ctypes import *

p = CDLL('./p.dll')
p.printing("help")
```

In my running window, It shows like this.

[image]

I thought it was a gcc error, so I ran the next code, but this code worked well.

This is my C code

```
//this is p.c File
#include <stdio.h>
void printing(char* string){
    printf("%s",string);
}

int test(int val){
    return val+30;
}
```

This is my compile code.

```
gcc --shared -op.dll p.o
gcc -fPIC -c p.c
```

This is my Python code

```
#This is my Python code
from ctypes import *

p = CDLL('./p.dll')
print(p.test(123))
```

[image]

As you can see, It shows me 153, 123 + 30 , that is the result of test(123)...

So how can I print out the "hello" I gave from Python in C code?

Comment: On my Kali linux your code works correctly. I think your gcc specifications/options doesn't generate a WIN DLL, unfortunately I am not aware of the windows specs for C-code and/or gcc to deploy a win dll.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved This problem.

```
#This is my Python code
from ctypes import *
args1 = "help"
args1.encode("euc-kr")
p = CDLL('./p.dll')
p.printing.argtypes = [c_char_p]
p.printing(args1)
```

Comment: On my Kali linux your code works correctly. I think your gcc specifications/options doesn't generate a WIN DLL, unfortunately I am not aware of the windows specs for C-code and/or gcc to deploy a win dll.

Comment: `char*` / `c_char_p` must be passed a Python byte string.  As you found, encoding a Python `str` (Unicode string) makes it a byte string.  You can also just pass a byte string directly, e.g. `p.printing(b'help')`.  As you also probably found, setting `.argtypes` and `.restype` correctly helps type check for errors when using the function.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Why does wookoo's code run correctly on my Kali-Linux?

Comment: @SirJoBlack Are you running Python 2?   Then `print('help')` passes a byte string.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm using: Python 2.7.18, I think is Python 2! (I tried with both char and wchar_t)